# Disable required Verification Code During Developer Login

Tags: salesforce-id, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I'm developing an app by using the SalesforceMobile SDK. It is time consuming to enter the verification code for every login.

I looked inside my Salesforce Developer Edition Platform but I was not able to disable this security feature (for developing purpose).

Is this feature defeatable?

Comment: did you whitelisted IP addresses ? 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255 in your profile.

Comment: No, I did not. I've to look where this setting is located. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Login IP Range in your profile which you are using to login. as below

[image]

Comment: it present in your profile.

Comment: If I enter these values, I get the error message "Error: Invalid Data. Error: The range specified is too large"

Comment: for exact same value?

Comment: Yes - I changed it up to my real external ip ranges and it works!

Comment: okay great it worked but wanted to know the reason for the 255.255.255.255 IP address because i tried this for more than three orgs but i did not get the error.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` - `1.255.255.255` seems to be valid. But I still need to enter a verification code. :/

Comment: what is the IP address of ur device ?

Comment: Dynamical changed

Comment: are u still getting error for 255.255.255.255 ?

Comment: Yes, I do. That's all a bit too tricky ...